# I am working on python django and have a registration form there are fields like username email password want to check if exists

Tags: python, django, database

I have a html form where there are fields like username, email, password I want to check individually if username exists or not by entering username also email exists or not by entering email in the html form also check both at same time if both exists or not the code I have written for this is not working for single field what I meant is if I enter only username it says username is taken also email is taken But I don't want that I want individually they exists or not and if I enter both existing email and username it should say email is taken and username is taken by displaying message. How can I modify the code to work like that

This is my views.py code

```
def Register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:

      
            email_taken = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
            username_taken = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()

            if email_taken:
               messages.error(request,"Email is taken.")
            

            if username_taken:
               messages.error(request,"Username is taken.")
              

            if email_taken or username_taken:
                return redirect('/register/')

            
            user_obj = User(username = username , email = email)
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
    
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user = user_obj )
            profile_obj.save()
            return redirect('/login/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return render(request , 'register.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check username and password in form and show error before he/she submit form,you have to use ajax to send request for every field that you have..unfortunately i havent example to show you but you got the idea..search for ajax in django.

Comment: Why ajax is needed I want to do a simple thing can you show a example or can you do some changes in my code to show that